# How to take a snapshot of the entire system of Macbook Pro OS x 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I want to be able to take a snapshot of the current system and will go back to it whenever I mess up with files. I looked at the Time Machine solution, but realized that it's only a good solution when I know what file I am looking for. But sometimes, some installation process creates binary files in multiple system paths, which are very hard to locate and identify. Say I installed a package, but then I felt like I shouldn't have done that. Uninstallation might still leave files around. So What might be some of the graceful solutions to go back to a status of the machine when everything is nice and clean.

Comment: You might have better luck over at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). StackOverflow is for *programming* questions, not system management ones.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd look at using Disk Utility.

Answer (score 2):

Use disk utility (Applications | Utilities)
Click on the HDD and then click on new image. You can choose to have a compressed image or not. If you don't have much stuff on the drive it shouldn't be more than 30-40GB. Once you have the dmg file, stick it somewhere for backup purposes.
Also, create a recovery disk/stick with the recovery tool.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno about "graceful" but [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com) is definitely an easy solution for rolling back to a previous state. You can make an exact clone of your drive, then restore it back if something goes horribly wrong. I use CCC to make periodic backups of my Macs, as a sort of secondary backup to time-machine, which is easy to use but which I don't have total confidence in.

Comment: [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) is another alternative for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore an entire system from a Time Machine snapshot, but it requires booting from the Recovery Partition or a Recovery disk.    Basically, once you've rebooted in recovery mode, you can choose `Restore From Time Machine Backup` and then you'll be asked to locate the drive.   Once you've done that, a list of Time Machine snapshots will be presented for restoring.

I haven't done this recently, but there are indications that the time of the backups may always be in PST, so be careful when looking at the times.

Answer (score 1):

While OSX comes with TimeMachine, it also has the well-known (in Linux community!) command line tool called rsync.

With Google, I'm sure you can find many articles of how to use it, though [here's](http://brian.windheim.org/2012/time-machine-sucks-use-rsync-instead) an interesting blog of why its author uses rsync with Time Machine.